# Decrease line spacing for inline itemize

Tags: line-spacing, enumitem

I'm making heavy use of inline lists. However, due to a tight page limit, I'd like to *reduce* the line spacing. Currently it looks like this. I've annotated the length I want to decrease.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize*}
        \item \lipsum[1]
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[3]
    \end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```

I've tried commands like `\setstretch{0.5}`and `\linespread{0.5}` but neither seems to have an effect. How can I decrease the line spacing in this situation?

[image]

Comment: use a smaller fontsize.

Comment: I'm not sure inline lists affect spacing at all; in your sample code,`\setstretch` should work if the `setspace` package is loaded, but really, don't do that.

Comment: So you want to decrease the line spacing only before lines where an item starts? This does not make any sense to me.

Comment: No no I mean the spacing between every line.

Comment: You can also set  a samaller `\baselikeskip`  to all the document. Or  only the one part (some like  `{\baselikeskip8pt ... \par}` where the ending  \par is important), but as @frabjous said, really, don't do that.